# working with arrays

Tags: php

I currently do a query which goes through the records and forms an array.
the print_r on query gives me this

```
print_r($query) yields the following:

Array (
[0] =>  ( [field1] => COMPLETE [field2] => UNKNOWN [field3] => Test comment )
[1] =>  ( [field1] => COMPLETE [field2] => UNKNOWN [field3] => comment here ) 
[2] =>  ( [field1] => COMPLETE [field2] => UNKNOWN [field3] => checking ) 
[3] =>  ( [field1] => COMPLETE [field2] => UNKNOWN [field3] => testing ) 
[4] =>  ( [field1] => COMPLETE [field2] => UNKNOWN [field3] => working )
)
```

somehow I want to take this array and convert it back to php. So for example some thing like this

```
$myArray = array( ...)
```

then $myArray should yield the samething as the print_r($query) yeilds.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `serialize` that's closer to the `print_r` output would be

- [`var_export`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) — Outputs or returns a parsable string representation of a variable

> var_export() gets structured information about the given variable. It is similar to var_dump()  with one exception: the returned representation is valid PHP code.

Note that

> var_export() does not handle circular references as it would be close to impossible to generate parsable PHP code for that. If you want to do something with the full representation of an array or object, use serialize().

Using var_export wouldn't allow you to parse back an actual `print_r` result. But tbh, I find attempting that not very feasible at all. If you have to do that, something is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I may be underestimating your PHP experience here, but....

You do realize that $query is an array, right? You can simply do `$myArray = $query` without using print_r() for anything.

Do you need to convert it to text and back? Does it have to be stored somewhere? If so, can you use a different format (serialized or json)?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$phpcode = "\$myarray = " . var_export($query, true) . ";";
```

This returns a string representation of your $query array that is valid PHP code.

*PS.  You're not thinking of using **eval()** on it later, are you?*

Answer (score -1):

```
$filedata = serialize($query);
// write $filedata to a file
```

Then in another file:

```
// some other php file
// read in the filedata
$filedata = file_get_contents("file.dat");
$query = unserialize($filedata);
```

This is what I assume you meant by converting a string representation of an array into PHP. If you want to actually convert the output of `print_r`, then you will need to do some serious regex.

Comment: yea I needed to convert print_r output to an array

Comment: I can do this
$rawData =      Array ('status' => 'COMPLETE', 'outcome' => 'UNKNOWN', 'location' => 'test');
      $serialized = serialize($rawData ); 
$myNewArray = unserialize($serialized); 
print_r($myNewArray);  

but that gives me only one array like this
Array ( [status] => COMPLETE [outcome] => UNKNOWN [location] => RIGHT ) 

how do I get 0, 1, 2,...
thanks

Comment: ok this works however I am not sure how to add stdClass Object 
 $rawData =      Array (array ('status' => 'COMPLETE', 'outcome' => 'UNKNOWN', 'location' => 'RIGHT'),
           array ('status' => 'NOTCOMPLETE', 'outcome' => 'Known', 'location' => 'Test'));
      $serialized = serialize($rawData ); 
$myNewArray = unserialize($serialized); 
print_r($myNewArray);  
yeilds:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [status] => COMPLETE [outcome] => UNKNOWN [location] => RIGHT ) [1] => Array ( [status] => NOTCOMPLETE [outcome] => Known [location] => Test ) ) 
its repeating array instead of stdClass object

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand what you mean. It is doing exactly what you provide the function. You didn't use stdClass anywhere in your array, so that is why it is not in the array itself. (That or your code is very hard to read in the comments - you should add it to your question)